# C# does not accept path within DotNetZip compression

Tags: c#, path, dotnetzip

I am struggling with C#, Ionic.Zip and the path declaration.
The error message is: The path format is not supported.
The path looks right, so no idea what's happening here...

This is my code:

```
string datetime = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("G");
datetime = String.Format("{0:yyyy_MM_dd}", datetime); 

string workingPath = @"C:\Users\udgru\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Skeleton\Skeleton\bin\Debug";
string backupDir = System.IO.Path.Combine(workingPath, "UserData");
string outputFile = "Backup_" + datetime + ".zip";

MessageBox.Show(workingPath);
// Output: C:\Users\udgru\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Skeleton\Skeleton\bin\Debug
MessageBox.Show(backupDir);
// Output: C:\Users\udgru\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Skeleton\Skeleton\bin\Debug\UserData
MessageBox.Show(outputFile);
// Output: Backup_2015_03_04 17:26:44.zip

        try
        {
            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {

                zip.AlternateEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = Ionic.Zip.ZipOption.Always;
                zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;
                zip.Comment = "This zip was created at " + datetime;
                zip.AddDirectory(backupDir);
                zip.Save(outputFile);

                MessageBox.Show("Backup successfully created.");

                FlyoutSettings.IsOpen = false;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Does `backupDir` really contain the string "workingPath\UserData"?  You should have gotten something like `C:\Users\udgru\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Skeleton\Skeleton\bin\Debug\UserData`

Comment: I updated my post to make it clear :-)

Comment: Please use file name only, not the path while
 zip.Save(outputFile);

Comment: Changed it but the error still appears... The string outputFile appears with space like "Backup_2015_03_04 17:26:44.zip" although I defined it as YYYY_MM_DD.

Comment: Just for the test give path to c drive only and test does it show any error?

Comment: may be you cannot use colons in file name!

Comment: Just to get you right: You want me to backup the whole C:\ drive???

Comment: yes, also you cannot use colons in file name, not accepted. This is wrong file name "Backup_2015_03_04 17:26:44.zip"

Comment: You are right. Just with underscores it's running now. Thanks to all of you!!!